# how to read special character from a file in verilog?

Tags: file-io, verilog, system-verilog

I wrote a test Verilog file reading some data from a file. The file has some header lines starting with `###` and repeated lines containing 8 float numbers all in text format, like below...

```
### kr = 0 ##
279.430 243.666 246.522 234.073 218.708 211.012 212.915 222.156
227.269 225.331 212.973 203.453 203.286 219.196 236.336 236.591
236.760 240.655 234.219 226.415 222.691 225.924 229.316 223.291
223.373 229.256 229.021 221.693 208.506 208.094 217.843 232.213
...
-0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000
-0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 2.624
### kr = 1 ##
192.269 28.298 0.356 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000
-0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 9.506 -0.000
-0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000 -0.000
-0.000 2.147 2.839 1.402 0.004 16.810 37.424 47.157
...
```

The code reading the file is like below.  (Actually, I have to read many files, but below is a simple code to test some aspects.).  I'm using system verilog.

```
integer file;
integer c;
initial begin
    fname = $sformatf("ext1/L02_Convolution_B0_FN%03d.txt",3);
    $dislay("fname = %s", fname);
    file = $fopen(fname, "r");
    c = $fgetc(file);
    while (c != `EOF)
        begin
        if (c == '#')
            r = $fgets(line, `MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
        else
            begin
            r = $ungetc(c, file);
            r = $fscanf(file, "%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7);
            $display("%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f \n",v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7);
            c = $fgetc(file);
            end
        end
    end
    r = $fclose(file);
end
```

When I compile it, I get this error:

```
ncvlog -SV tb_conv.v
ncvlog: 12.20-s008: (c) Copyright 1995-2013 Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
        if (c == '#')
                  |
ncvlog: *E,BADBSE (tb_conv.v,47|12): illegal base specification: (#) [2.5][2.5.1(IEEE)].
```

The compiler thinks 'c' is an integer and should have a base indicator like 0x or 0o, I guess. But, I want to test if it is a special character '#'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable `c` as `string`. Since you are using `$fgetc(file);` which gets a character. A common syntax for string comparison is using double quotes like `c== "#"`.